# error: ‘template’ (as a disambiguator) is only allowed within templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, boost-multi-index, gcc4.5

I have following definitions:

```
typedef  boost::multi_index_container<
  ModelPtr,
   boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    boost::multi_index::sequenced<boost::multi_index::tag<byInsertOrder> >, // to keep order of inserting
    boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique< boost::multi_index::tag<byPriority>,
                                            boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<IModel,
                                            unsigned int,
                                            &IModel::getPriority>,
                                            std::greater< unsigned int> // from the highest priority to the lowest
                                            >
    >
  > ModelContainer;

typedef ModelContainer::template index<AOActivationList::byInsertOrder>::type ModelByInsertOrderType; (*)
```

The problem is that when I try to compile it with gcc 4.5.3 I get following error:
error: ‘template’ (as a disambiguator) is only allowed within templates
In line marked with (*). In Visual Studio 2008 it compiles.

What is the reason of that? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
typedef ModelContainer::template index<AOActivationList::byInsertOrder>::type ModelByInsertOrderType
```

remove the word `template`, unless you are within a `template`, as using `ModelContainer::template ...` is only valid if `ModelContainer` is a type dependent on non-fixed `template` parameters in the current scope.

If the compiler could figure out the full type of `ModelContainer` on that line, the use of `template` is not allowed.  If it couldn't figure it out for certain, then the use of `template` is required.

Visual studio's decision to compile or not compile a given chunk of code is rarely good evidence that the code is valid C++ by any standard.